# Google say: robots.txt not valid for subdomains?

Tags: seo, google-search, subdomain, sitemap, robots.txt

I'm very confused about [Google's robots.txt documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)

> Examples of valid robots.txt URLs:
>
> Not valid for
>   `http://other.example.com/`
>   `https://example.com/`
>   `http://example.com:8181/`

It says the robots.txt is not valid for subdomains. Is that correct? If yes, what if we have different contents with main domain?

Comment: You seem to have misquoted (or misunderstood) the docs... that table states that the particular robots.txt file located at `http://example.com/robots.txt` is _not valid for_ the URLs you have quoted above, not that those URLs are invalid locations for the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a robots.txt in the root web directory of your subdomain, just like you do for your main domain. You have to think of the subdomain as a separate website in this case.

Comment: Yes, i have a robots.txt on the web root directory of subdomain. So, the google documentation is wrong?

Comment: They are correct. What they are saying is the robots.txt file for the main domain will not affect the subdomain. The subdomain needs its own robots.txt file.